# Is it possible to add Piecharts to d3 tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, pie-chart

I have been searching for a working example of a chart inside tooltips of the another chart. I have not been able to find something so far.  I am wondering if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, probably it is not very common but as far as I know it is possible and you just need to append the new D3 SVG drawing into the tooltip with the function

```
d3.select("#tooltip").append("svg:svg") //Line 252
```

On this [D3 chart tooltip JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/v95x18rt/) I'm adding a D3 chart to the `#tooltip` element.